Simple assignment versus push method in prototypal inheritance
Say I have this block of code:
let hamster = {
  stomach: [],

  eat(food) {
    this.stomach.push(food);
  }
};

let speedy = {
  __proto__: hamster
};

let lazy = {
  __proto__: hamster
};

speedy.eat("apple");
alert( speedy.stomach ); // apple
.
alert( lazy.stomach ); // apple

Both speedy and lazy objects share the same stomach array, but when I instead use a simple assignment for the eat function :
  eat(food) {
    // assign to this.stomach instead of this.stomach.push
    this.stomach = [food];
  }
};

For the simple assignment hey have different stomach arrays.
Both cases behave differently but why is that? Yet both use the 'this' keyword.

This has nothing to do with the this keyword or the method. The issue is the same when you do speedy.stomach.push(…) vs speedy.stomach = […].

Hint: speedy.stomach === lazy.stomach because both inherit the same array from hamster.stomach. Try hamster.eat('nuts') and observe speedy and lazy.

Prototypes are only used when searching for an existing property. When assigning to a property, it always writes to that object, it doesn't search the prototype chain.
